Meaning of 声にして
What does 声にして mean in this phrase?

声にして伝える

にして is the te-form of にする, which means "to make, choose, or change into something." I heard にして can also work as a way to say "and" similarly to で. So, does the phrase mean "to turn something into a voice (put something into words) and convey it"?

Without further context, this sounds like, "to articulate" or "to put into words".

It's part of the song lyrics here: https://finalfantasy.fandom.com/wiki/Kimi_ga_Irukara#Lyrics

It sounds to me like "to articulate", "to express", or "to put into words".
The full phrase is

素直な気持ち　譲れないもの 正直な言葉　全て 声にして伝える事ができたなら


The singer is listing several things 素直な気持ち, 譲れないもの, and 正直な言葉.  Then they sing 全て 声にして伝える事ができたなら.
声にして does not mean the same thing as 言葉.  The singer is saying,

if I could give voice to these things and pass them on [to you]

which, in brief, I could rather loosely express as

if I could articulate these things [for you]

or

if I could put these things into words [for you]


So, 声 can mean the same as 言葉 in this case?

@A.T.A. I've updated the answer.  Does that clarify?

Yes, it helps a lot.
